# How to make the backgroundcolor of TDCalendarView transparent?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am using TDCalendarView in my application. Problem is that whatever I do -- after loading, the calendar page shows background as white. When I set it's background color as clearColor, when the page is popping up I can see it's clear color. But when the page if full loaded a white backbround appears.

What should I do to remove this white background?

Answer (score 0):

IM not too sure on how to comment, but when a background is "clearColor", it is like there is no background at all! if you want an image behind the view, then add a UIImage behind the TDCalendarView and then set the Calendar's view to clearColor and then you will be able to see the picture. The white background is because that is the color of the actual view which is behind the calendar view. If you want a solid color behind the calendar, change the color of the UIView's background Hope that helps :D